# Restructure and Select Value based on Conditions with Loop

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to restructure the following student testing data (df_test) to create a list of answer keys.
Q1.C, Q2.C, Q3.C...Q20.C shows whether a student's answer in Q1,Q2... is correct. Q1.CH, Q2.CH,...Q20.CH shows a student's answer in each question.

```
print (df_test)
```

| StudentID | Q1.C | Q2.C | Q3.C | ... | Q20.C | Q1.CH | Q2.CH | Q3.CH | ... | Q20.CH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 1 | 0 | ... | 1 | A | C | C | ... | B |
| 002 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... | 1 | C | C | D | ... | B |
| 003 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 0 | A | C | B | ... | D |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 201 | 1 | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 | A | C | D | ... | C |

Outcome data frame should look like

| Question | Answer_Key |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | A |
| Q2 | C |
| Q3 | B |
| Q... | ... |
| Q20 | B |

Can anyone help? Thank you.

I tried to create a series of table and stack all the tables together. It works fine when there are only 20 questions in an assessment. However, some assessments have over 100 questions. It takes too much manual work. I tried for-loop to create the table, not successful.

```
x1<-data.frame(table(df_test$Q1.CH,df_test$Q1.C))%>%
   subset(Freq!=0 & Var2==1)%>%
   mutate(Question_ID="Q1")%>%
   select(Var1,Question_ID)
x2<-data.frame(table(df_test$Q2.CH,df_test$Q2.C))%>%
   subset(Freq!=0 & Var2==1)%>%
  mutate(Question_ID="Q2")%>%
  select(Var1,Question_ID)

x20<-data.frame(table(df_test$Q20.CH,df_test$Q20.C))%>%
  subset(Freq!=0 & Var2==1)%>%
  mutate(Question_ID="Q20")%>%
  select(Var1,Question_ID)
x<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "^x")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using a for-loop for this, with an example below. I have partially recreated the dataset with three questions.

```
df_test <- data.frame(StudentID = c("001", "002", "003"),
                      Q1.C = c(1, 0, 1),
                      Q2.C = c(1, 1, 1),
                      Q3.C = c(0, 0, 1), 
                      Q1.CH = c("A", "C", "A"),
                      Q2.CH = c("C", "C", "C"),
                      Q3.CH = c("C", "D", "B"))


# Here I try to get all the questions (in my example, Q1 to Q3)
Question <- names(df_test)[grepl("Q.*C$", names(df_test))]
Question <- gsub("\\.C", "", Question)

# This is an empty vector initialized to get the answers in the upcoming loop
Answer_Key <- rep("", length(Question))

for(i in 1:length(Question)){
  # This is an inefficient (code-wise) process, but it gets the task done
  # I temporarily renamed the question columns, these will be renamed back later
  Col1 <- paste0(Question[i], ".C")
  Col2 <- paste0(Question[i], ".CH")
  
  # The renamed columns make it easier for referring to the question columns throughout the column when the questions change
  names(df_test)[names(df_test) == Col1] <- "Col1"
  names(df_test)[names(df_test) == Col2] <- "Col2"
  
 if(nrow(df_test[df_test[, "Col1"] == 1, "Col2"]) > 0){
    # It is assumed that all correct answers are the same, so only the first one will be taken
    Answer_Key[i] <- df_test[df_test[, "Col1"] == 1, "Col2"][1]
    
  } else {
    # If no students got a particular question correct, it will return NA
    Answer_Key[i] <- NA
    
  }
  
  names(df_test)[names(df_test) == "Col1"] <- Col1
  names(df_test)[names(df_test) == "Col2"] <- Col2
  
}

# This is the final output containing all questions and answers
x <- cbind(Question, Answer_Key)
```